# bash text manipulation from comma delimited variable to list

Tags: linux, bash, text-manipulation

I'm a novice at manipulating text in bash and appreciate any suggestions!

I have a variable used early in a script that is formatted like this:

```
runlist=echo 10,19,25,32
```

The actual numbers and how many numbers there are listed out differ on various iterations. They will always be 2 digits each. I need the variable in this format for the first step they are used for. But later in the script, I'd like to print out these numbers to a temporary text file in a single column like this

```
cat tmp_runlist.txt
10
19
25
32
```

I tried using `IFS=','` but found that it also modified the runlist variable, which is used again towards the end of the script. I've been exploring using `cut` and `awk` but need something that can be flexible in just grabbing the characters between the commas and not taking the commas before the carriage return.

Thanks in advance for your ideas :)

Comment: Your variable is the entire `echo .....` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that instead of

```
runlist=echo 10,19,25,32
```

you meant

```
runlist=$(echo 10,19,25,32)
```

...or just

```
runlist=10,19,25,32
```

In that case, the simplest way should be to use

```
echo "$runlist" | tr , '\n'
```

If it really is

```
runlist=echo 10,19,25,32
```

then you might use

```
echo "$runlist" | sed 's/^echo *//;s/,/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep -o` might help:

```
s='10,19,25,32'
grep -o '[0-9]\+' <<< "$s"
10
19
25
32
```